# Visualise time dependent transitions/event sequences

Tags: data-visualization

Consider the following example dataset consisting of road accidents where both an ambulance and police are called onto scene. There are two possible sequences of events:

```
Accident --> Police arrives --> Ambulance arrives
Accident --> Ambulance arrives --> Police arrives
```

If we were interested in visualising how often police arrives first vs ambulance, we could draw a flow chart like

```
Accident -- 70% --> Police arrives -- 100% --> Ambulance arrives
   |
   \-- 30% --> Ambulance arrives -- 100% --> Police Arrives
```

Now I am also interested in visualising the time between these events. E.g., maybe in the 70% of the time when police arrives first, sometimes it takes a minute, sometimes it takes 10 minutes. Does anyone have any suggestions to combine such a visualisation with the flow chart, so that you get both the sense of how often a sequence happens, and how long it takes for the sequence to happen?

Comment: Old question, but if it's still of interest to you, you could simply make the length of each branch proportional to the mean time of each event. For instance, when police arrives first, if the mean time of police arriving is 5 min, use a length of 5 cm. Same thing for the other branches, where 1 minute = 1 cm. You would have to make explicit that the length is related to time, so it may require adding a time scale above or under the flow chart.